# How find all the filenames when a list of file name fragments inputed using python glob?

Tags: python-3.x, filenames, glob, python-os

I have a list of file name fragments, and I want to return a list of all the file names under a certain directory.

I wrote this code to tackle this problem, but it turns out that is a rather slow solution.

```py
train_file_list = []
for p in patient_list[:n_train]:
    file = glob(os.path.join("D:\preprocess_data\Positive", p + "*.npz"))
    train_file_list.append(file)
```

Hopefully, I can rely on your talent to come up with a more efficient way to do this. Thanks!!!